# Show exception message in lightning without stacktrace APEX?

Tags: apex, lightning-experience, exception

I want to show a duplicateRule message Error without showing stacktrace and the line of my code where the error is.

I tried with this :

```
public class applicationException extends Exception {}


        List <Database.UpsertResult> upsertResult = Database.upsert(objectToBeUpdated, false);
            
    for(Database.UpsertResult sr : upsertResult ){
        if (!sr.isSuccess()) {

            for(Database.Error error : sr.getErrors()){

                if(error.getStatusCode() == SYSTEM.StatusCode.DUPLICATES_DETECTED){
                Datacloud.DuplicateResult duplicateResult = ((Database.DuplicateError)error).getDuplicateResult();
                throw new applicationException(duplicateResult.getErrorMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And I have always stacktrace with message , I tried also with this and i have same result

```
throw new AuraHandledException
```

Here is my error : [image]

I want to shwo just : The Email addresses must be unique

Comment: Please post error message structure

Comment: @amitghadage Done

Answer (score 0):

If you throw an exception, you'll get a stack trace. That's how exceptions work. Instead, return the success values to the client so it can show success/error in whatever manner you've set up on the client. Note that this means you'll reduce the number of try-catch blocks you need on both the client and server.